# How to show closure of ball of radius r/2 is a subset of ball with radius r

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that the neighborhood $\overline{N_{r/2}(x)}$ (the bar is really small but that's the closure) is a subset of $N_{r}(x)$.

I split it up so that I know if $y \in \overline{N_{r/2}(x)}$ then y is either a limit point or an element of $N_{r/2}(x)$. If it's an element then it's pretty straightforward but I don't know what to do if it's a limit point. Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting $N_{r}(x)$ as the ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$ in a metric space. Correct me if I'm wrong there.

If $y\in\overline{N_{r/2}(x)}$ then there exists a sequence $y_n$ such that
$$y_n\in N_{r/2}(x)\text{ and } y_n\rightarrow y$$
We therefore have
$$|y_n-x|<\dfrac{r}{2}$$
for every $n$. Can you go to the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and conclude?

Answer (score 0):

This echoes the other answer but, the closure of the open $r/2$ ball centered at $0$, is pretty easily nothing but the closed $r/2$ ball.  Clearly the latter is contained in the $r$ ball.
That is, if we're in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: In a general metric space, the closure of an open ball is only a subset (the inclusion could be strict) of the closed ball of same radius. In $\Bbb{R}^n$ this problem disappears however.